# WCF service POST method not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

i am getting following error when i call the wcf service using ajax from another project :

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details.

i have created the following wcf service in a project :

IService1.cs -

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int AddNumbers(int a);

    [OperationContract]
    string ShowMsg();

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

service1.cs -

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public int AddNumbers(int a)
    {
        return a + 5;
    }

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string ShowMsg()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

and this is how i am consuming it from another project :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:16748/Service1.svc/AddNumbers",
            contenType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ a: 4 }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#elementsDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = xhr.responseText;
                $("#elementsDiv").html(err);
            }
        });
```

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have a typo in your ajax call:

```
contenType: 'application/json',
```

I think this should be:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

other than that your code runs fine for me.